# Which account will hue use to run hive query?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

Let's say I use the username "test" to login HUE and execute a query on HIVE.
Which user will hue use to execute the hive query?
The user "test" or the user "hue" or the user "hive"?

Comment: Depends how you configured Hue. Run a query... Look at the YARN UI and find out

Comment: Default behavior, as far as I remember, is to run as "test" user.